# I cannot get my hangman program to break when the user runs out of guesses

Tags: python, project, break

***THIS IS HOMEWORK***
I am trying to get the program to break when the user says that they don't want to play anymore, but I can't get it to work. The program tells the user to try again but keeps the same word and doesn't break. Is there something wrong with my loops? If not, what could the issue be and how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance

```
def playGame():
    '''This function allows you to play hangman'''

    print("Welcome to Hangman")
    print("   -------") 
    print("   |     |") 
    print("         |") 
    print("         |") 
    print("         |") 
    print("     -----")
    #def randword(List):
        #wr=random.randint(0,len(List)-1)
        #return List[wr]
    global wordlist
    hangman=open('hangman.txt','r+')
    wordlist=hangman.read()
    x=random.randint(0,len(wordlist)-1)
    w=random.choice(wordlist)
    print (w)
    blanks= '_ ' * len(w)
    #for i in range(len(w)):
       #print('_',sep=" ")
    #print()   
    guesses=[]
    correct=[]
    mistakes=0
    correctguess=0
    guessNumber=0

    while guessNumber<=6:
        print(blanks)
        letter=str(input("Take a guess?"))
        if letter in guesses:
            print("You tried that already! Enter another letter!")
            continue
        if len(letter) > 1:
            print("""Enter ONE letter!""")
        if letter not in guesses:
            guesses.append(letter)
        if letter in w:
            print("You got one, keep going")
            correct.append(letter)
            print (correct)
            for i in range(len(w)):
                if w[i]in correct:
                    correctguess=correctguess+1
                    if len(correct) == len(w):
                        print("You got it! The word was",w,)
                        replay=str(input(""" Want to try again? Enter yes or no"""))
                        if replay=='yes' or replay=='YES' or replay=='Yes':
                            playGame()
                        if replay=='no' or replay=='NO' or replay=='n' or replay=='this game sucked':
                            print("Well, have a nice day then")
                            break
        elif letter not in w:
            mistakes=mistakes+1
            if mistakes == 1: 
                print("   -------") 
                print("   |     |") 
                print("   o     |")
                print("         |") 
                print("         |") 
                print("     -----")
            if mistakes == 2: 
                print("   -------") 
                print("   |     |") 
                print("   o     |") 
                print("   |     |") 
                print("         |") 
                print("     -----") 
            if mistakes == 3: 
                print("   -------") 
                print("   |     |") 
                print("   o     |") 
                print("  /|     |") 
                print("         |") 
                print("     -----") 
            if mistakes == 4: 
                print("   -------") 
                print("   |     |") 
                print("   o     |") 
                print("  /|\    |") 
                print("         |") 
                print("     -----") 
            if mistakes == 5: 
                print("   -------") 
                print("   |     |") 
                print("   o     |") 
                print("  /|\    |") 
                print("  /      |") 
                print("     -----") 
            if mistakes == 6: 
                print("   -------") 
                print("   |     |") 
                print("   o     |") 
                print("  /|\    |") 
                print("  / \    |") 
                print("     -----") 
                print("You did not get the word. Try again!")
                replay=str(input(""" Want to try again? Enter yes or no"""))
                if replay=='yes' or replay=='YES' or replay=='Yes':
                    playGame()
                if replay=='no' or replay=='NO' or replay=='n' or replay=='this game sucked':
                    print("Well, have a nice day then")
                    break                
            print(guesses)
            guessNumber = guessNumber+1
```

Comment: Stack overflow won't do your homework for you. Whoever gave you the homework undoubtedly supplied you with more appropriate resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think break only gets out of the inner most loop.  See: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break

I believe what you are looking for is [sys.exit()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) if you want to quit the program.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are calling `playGame()` recursively. When you break, you are dropping back in to the loop, probably with a different word selected. There's a couple of ways you could handle it. One would be to call `sys.exit()` when you want to quit. A second way would be to have a variable passed to know you need to exit, and check for that variable in the while loop. Or perhaps even better, take the logic to decide if you should play again outside of the loop. A simple example of this can be seen below. Just replace your code block with a `break` statement to end the game, which will drop down into the main game loop, as specified below.

```
while (True):
    playGame()
    replay=str(input(""" Want to try again? Enter yes or no"""))
    replay=replay.lower();   # This line converts to lower case, removing some checks.
    if replay=='no' or or replay=='n' or replay=='this game sucked':
          print("Well, have a nice day then")
          break
```

Comment: Thanks you guys! I really appreciate it, the sys.exit() is what I went with; at first it wasn't working, but I looked it up and learned that I had to import sys and it's working like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys.exit()` or `raise SystemExit`

```
... 
print("You did not get the word. Try again!")
replay=str(input(""" Want to try again? Enter yes or no"""))
if replay=='yes' or replay=='YES' or replay=='Yes':
    playGame()
if replay=='no' or replay=='NO' or replay=='n' or replay=='this game sucked':
    print("Well, have a nice day then")
    sys.exit()
    #raise SystemExit
...
```

That will completely end the program.